# How to create a Boolean Series based on the logic: (0 followed by a 1 is True. A 1 preceded by a 0 is True. All others are False)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF. I'm Trying to make a Boolean Series where the logic is: 
(0 followed by a 1 is True. A 1 preceded by a 0 is True. All others are False)

Here is the DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 1}})                                                                                                                                                                                 

    A
0   1
1   0
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   0
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
10  0
11  0
12  1
```

Expected Output (0 followed by a 1 is True. A 1 preceded by a 0 is True. All others are False:

```
    A  Truth
0   1  False
1   0   True
2   1   True
3   1  False
4   1  False
5   0   True
6   1   True
7   1  False
8   1  False
9   1  False
10  0  False
11  0   True
12  1   True
```

My ouput using:  df['Truth'] = df['A'] == 0 | ( (df['A'].shift() == 0) & (df['A'] == 1) )

```
    A  Truth
0   1  False
1   0   True
2   1   True
3   1  False
4   1  False
5   0   True
6   1   True
7   1  False
8   1  False
9   1  False
10  0   True
11  0   True
12  1   True
```

I'm getting True on a zero, but a zero should only by True if followed by one, and not another zero. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
cond1 = df['A'].diff().shift(-1).eq(1).where(df['A']==0)
df['Truth'] = df['A'].diff().eq(1).where(df['A'] == 1).fillna(cond1).astype('bool')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A  Truth
0   1  False
1   0   True
2   1   True
3   1  False
4   1  False
5   0   True
6   1   True
7   1  False
8   1  False
9   1  False
10  0  False
11  0   True
12  1   True
```

Check condition 1 and only set it where A == 0 then check condition 2 and only set it where A == 1, use fillna to combine the two condtions.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that works for me! I was trying different boolean equalities, but this works!

Comment: Yeah... this can probably be optimized somehow.  But using diff helps with logic.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `rolling` `sum` should be 1

```
df.A.rolling(2).sum()==1

0   False
1    True
2    True
3   False
4   False
5    True
6    True
7   False
8   False
9   False
10   True
11  False
12   True
```

Comment: 10 and 11 should be swapped. I got that one too in my testing :-)  10 should be False and 11 should be True

Answer (score 1):

You can use your logic:

```
df['A'] != df['A'].shift(fill_value=df['A'].iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
0     False
1      True
2      True
3     False
4     False
5      True
6      True
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True
11    False
12     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: 10 and 11 should be swapped. I got that one too in my testing :-) 10 should be False and 11 should be True